# When is $1+e^{-i\pi(a+b)}+e^{-i\pi(b+c)}+e^{-i\pi(a+c)}$ non-zero, $a$, $b$ and $c$ being integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers

I am trying to find the conditions on the integers $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that $$1+e^{-i\pi(a+b)}+e^{-i\pi(b+c)}+e^{-i\pi(a+c)}$$ is not equal to zero. I think that the conditions for which it is equal to zero are:

$$a=0, b=0, c=1$$
$$a=0, b=1, c=0$$
$$a=1, b=0, c=0$$

So I think the conditions I want are that no two of $a$, $b$ and $c$ are zero while the third is 1. Am I right and how could I state this better?

Comment: looks fine to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Euler's identity: $e^{i\pi}=-1$, so also $e^{-i\pi}=-1$

Therefore you are asking when $$1+ (-1)^{a+b} + (-1)^{b+c} + (-1)^{a+c}$$

is not equal to 0. This is when:

1. One of $a+b$, $b+c$, $a+c$ is odd.
2. $a+b$, $b+c$, $a+c$ are all even.
3. $a+b$, $b+c$, $a+c$ are all odd.

Case 1 and 3 are not possible, suppose without loss of generality that $a+b$ is odd, then $a$ and $b$ have different parity, so $a+c$ and $b+c$ have different parity.

Case 2 is exactly when $a,b,c$ are all even, or all odd. If $a+b$ is even, then if both $a$ and $b$ are even, $c$ must be even and if both $a$ and $b$ are odd, $c$ must be odd.